# Matching approaches: hard match with propensity score (or logit) or hard match followed by propensity score matching

Tags: propensity-scores, matching

I have a population-based cohort and am exploring between two approaches to 1:1 matching:

1. Hard matching that includes the logit of the propensity score (one step)
2. Hard matching then creating a propensity score and performing propensity score matching (two steps)

I've found papers that use approach 1 and papers that use approach 2, but I can't seem to find any references that discuss the methodological rationale behind these two approaches. Any suggestions or guidebooks appreciated.

Comment: What is hard matching?

Comment: Another term might be 'exact matching', where are trying to ensure that matched pairs have the same attributes (e.g., hard match on date of birth+/-90 days and sex ensures that pairs are born within +/-90 days from each other and that they are the same sex)

Comment: Can you link to some papers that do both?

Comment: Widjaja E, Guttmann A, Tomlinson G, Snead III OC, Sander B. Economic burden of epilepsy in children: A population‐based matched cohort study in Canada. Epilepsia. 2021 Jan;62(1):152-62. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33258123/.... Angriman F, Rosella LC, Lawler PR, Ko DT, Wunsch H, Scales DC. Sepsis hospitalization and risk of subsequent cardiovascular events in adults: a population-based matched cohort study. Intensive Care Medicine. 2022 Apr;48(4):448-57. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/35142896/

Comment: 1step...Gomes.2022. Duration of use and outcomes among people with opioid use disorder initiating methadone and buprenorphine in Ontario: a population‐based propensity‐score matched cohort study. Addiction. Mac. Healthcare costs and outcomes associated with laboratory-confirmed Lyme disease in Ontario, Canada: A population-based cohort study. Plos one. 2023.   Thampi 2021. Health care costs of hospitalization of young children for respiratory syncytial virus infections: A population-based matched cohort study. CMA Open Access Journal.

Comment: I talked with a few colleagues who think the two-step process meant that they tried hard matching only, and then hard matching with propensity score (simultaneous).